# Как анимировать криволинейную границу объекта?

Tags: javascript, вёрстка, svg, canvas

Имеется вот такой объект на сайте:

[image: Объект]

Данная "клякса" имеет криволинейную границу по правой и нижней стороне.

Картинка статична, но я приведу ссылку с тем, как это уже реализовано [на одном из популярных сервисов](https://discordapp.com/login).

Хотелось бы узнать, как реализовать данный эффект? Интересует только анимация этих "скруглений".

В каком направлении можно найти хотя бы приближённую информацию?
На данном сайте используется canvas для отрисовки объекта, но я знаю точно, что такое можно провернуть и на SVG.

Comment: могу оказать как сделать подобное как на svg так и на canvas, если угодно - webgl

Answer (score 14, accepted):

То что в макете больше всего напоминает синусоиду в [полярных координатах](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82).

Начнем с окружности, в полярной системе координат (d - расстояние, t - угол) ее формула крайне проста:

```
 d = r; // d - расстояние до точки равно радиусу оркужности.
```

Как это понимать: представьте что вы взяли в руки циркуль и чертите окружность. Вроде все. Расстояние до каждой точки окружности от центра неизменно и равно радиусу. Значение радиуса от угла неизменно.

Если во время поворота циркуля менять его радиус в зависимости от угла и сделать эту завистмость в виде синусоиды - получится форма подобная той, что в макете

```
d = r + sin(t*freq)*amp; // freq - частота, amp - амплитуда.
```

А если добавить в эту зависимость время - получится анимация.

```js
let lerp = (a, b, val) => a + val * (b - a);   // линейная интерполяция
let rand = n => (Math.sin(n)*43758.5453123)%1; // псевдо случайное число

https://joshondesign.com/2013/03/01/improvedEasingEquations
function easeOutElastic(t) {
    var p = 0.5;
    return Math.pow(2,-10*t) * Math.sin((t-p/4)*(2*Math.PI)/p) + 1;
}

// одномерный шум
let noise = p => {
  let fl = Math.floor(p);
  return lerp(rand(fl), rand(fl + 1.0), p%1);
}

requestAnimationFrame(draw);

function draw(t) {
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  t = Math.max(0, t - 200); // небольшая задержка на старте
  let pts = "0,0";
  // для каждого угла в первой четверти окружности с шагом 0.01 радиан считаем точку
  for (var a = 0; a <= Math.PI/2; a += 0.01) {
    a %= Math.PI*2; // нормализуем угол
    // анимация увеличения радиуса кляксы на старте до значения 90
    let grow = Math.min(1, t/1000);
    grow = easeOutElastic(grow)
    let r = grow*70 // добавляем к базовому радиусу синус и косинус от времени и угла.
          + Math.cos(a*11 - t/379) * 2*grow
          + Math.sin(a*17 + noise(t/1e4)*15) * 3*grow;
    pts += "," + Math.cos(a)*r + "," + Math.sin(a)*r; 
  }
  shape.setAttribute('points', pts);
}
```

```css
body { margin:0;overflow:hidden; }
```

```html
<svg viewbox=0,0,100,100 height=100vh>
  <polygon id=shape></polygon>
</svg>
```

Добавил элемент псевдо случайности, так веселее

Comment: Ваш ответ как всегда хорош, но я выбираю тот что будет попроще, ещё раз спасибо за ваши ответы на SO.

Comment: @MoloF видимо кому что проще =), мне проще когда за меня компьютер считает, но есть и сторонники все руками сделать =)

Comment: @MoloF Коль уж Вам понравился мой ответ, я потрудился, написал объяснения, если что-то осталось не понятно - скажите я постараюсь дополнить :)

Comment: даже ваш первый вариант был понятен, ваш ответ выбран в связи с большей кастомизацией. Оба ответа на самом деле хороши, но уже не знаю что и выбрать, js больше симпатизирует, на нем пожалуй и остановлюсь.

Answer (score 9):

Подобная анимация реализуется с помощью изменения атрибута "d" path.

- Сначала нужно получить форму кривой в начальном положении:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Затем с помощью перемещения узловых точек кривой в векторном
  редакторе получаем финальную форму кривой :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее пишем команду анимации кривой:

`<animate attributeName="d" values="path1 ; path2 ; path1" />`

```css
svg {
width:40%;
height:40%;
}
path {
fill:#2F3136;
stroke:black;
stroke-width:4;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="770" height="770" viewBox="0 0 770 770" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >

<path d="M8.1 1.2V721.6c0 0 73.2 20.7 105 16.1 39.9-5.6 63.5-61.7 105-66.9 35-4.4 74.9 1 105-13.8 41.9-20.7 60.2-90.1 92.3-108.4 30.9-17.7 74.9-13.9 101.5-33.5 63.3-46.3 5.3-81.5 76.1-145.3 0 0 47.9-24.3 61.1-46.1 19.6-32.3 18.5-61.6 18.5-111.9 0-21.7 15.2-38.8 32.3-56.5C730.2 121.6 752.7 68.8 719.8 2.9 516.8-0.6 218-0.6 8.1 1.2Z" >
<animate attributeName="d"
  dur="8s"
  values="
         M8.1 1.2V721.6c0 0 73.2 20.7 105 16.1 39.9-5.6 63.5-61.7 105-66.9 35-4.4 74.9 1 105-13.8 41.9-20.7 60.2-90.1 92.3-108.4 30.9-17.7 74.9-13.9 101.5-33.5 63.3-46.3 5.3-81.5 76.1-145.3 0 0 47.9-24.3 61.1-46.1 19.6-32.3 18.5-61.6 18.5-111.9 0-21.7 15.2-38.8 32.3-56.5C730.2 121.6 752.7 68.8 719.8 2.9 516.8-0.6 218-0.6 8.1 1.2Z;
   M8.1 1.2V721.6c0 0 76.8 2.3 110.7-24.2 67.7-52.9 94.4-1.3 137.3-18.5 40.1-16.1 39.1-57.3 105-76.1 93.8-26.8 81.5-74.9 124.6-109.6 22.3-17.9 50.6-23.4 69.2-50.8 41.5-61.1 14.5-80.4 66.9-115.4 0 0 28.1-21.9 36.9-36.9 16.5-28.3 27.7-30.3 26.5-94.6-0.4-21.7 2.5-76.9 19.6-94.6C730.2 67.3 752.7 68.8 719.8 2.9 516.8-0.6 218-0.6 8.1 1.2Z;
   M8.1 1.2V721.6c0 0 73.2 20.7 105 16.1 39.9-5.6 63.5-61.7 105-66.9 35-4.4 74.9 1 105-13.8 41.9-20.7 60.2-90.1 92.3-108.4 30.9-17.7 74.9-13.9 101.5-33.5 63.3-46.3 5.3-81.5 76.1-145.3 0 0 47.9-24.3 61.1-46.1 19.6-32.3 18.5-61.6 18.5-111.9 0-21.7 15.2-38.8 32.3-56.5C730.2 121.6 752.7 68.8 719.8 2.9 516.8-0.6 218-0.6 8.1 1.2Z"
   repeatcount="indefinite"
   />
   
</path>

</svg>
```

- *Вариант с фоновой картинкой и тенью*

```css
.container {
width:75%;
height:75%;

}

path {
fill:#2F3136;
stroke:black;
stroke-width:0;
fill-opacity:0.5;
-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(4px 4px 1px black);
    filter: drop-shadow(4px 4px 1px black);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"  viewBox="0 0 770 770" preserveAspectRatio="none" >
<image  xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABxSm.jpg" x="10" width="1125px" height="750px" >
 
</image>
<path   d="M8.1 1.2V721.6c0 0 73.2 20.7 105 16.1 39.9-5.6 63.5-61.7 105-66.9 35-4.4 74.9 1 105-13.8 41.9-20.7 60.2-90.1 92.3-108.4 30.9-17.7 74.9-13.9 101.5-33.5 63.3-46.3 5.3-81.5 76.1-145.3 0 0 47.9-24.3 61.1-46.1 19.6-32.3 18.5-61.6 18.5-111.9 0-21.7 15.2-38.8 32.3-56.5C730.2 121.6 752.7 68.8 719.8 2.9 516.8-0.6 218-0.6 8.1 1.2Z" >
<animate id="an_d" attributeName="d"
  dur="8s"
  begin="0s"
  values="
         M8.1 1.2V721.6c0 0 73.2 20.7 105 16.1 39.9-5.6 63.5-61.7 105-66.9 35-4.4 74.9 1 105-13.8 41.9-20.7 60.2-90.1 92.3-108.4 30.9-17.7 74.9-13.9 101.5-33.5 63.3-46.3 5.3-81.5 76.1-145.3 0 0 47.9-24.3 61.1-46.1 19.6-32.3 18.5-61.6 18.5-111.9 0-21.7 15.2-38.8 32.3-56.5C730.2 121.6 752.7 68.8 719.8 2.9 516.8-0.6 218-0.6 8.1 1.2Z;
   M8.1 1.2V721.6c0 0 76.8 2.3 110.7-24.2 67.7-52.9 94.4-1.3 137.3-18.5 40.1-16.1 39.1-57.3 105-76.1 93.8-26.8 81.5-74.9 124.6-109.6 22.3-17.9 50.6-23.4 69.2-50.8 41.5-61.1 14.5-80.4 66.9-115.4 0 0 28.1-21.9 36.9-36.9 16.5-28.3 27.7-30.3 26.5-94.6-0.4-21.7 2.5-76.9 19.6-94.6C730.2 67.3 752.7 68.8 719.8 2.9 516.8-0.6 218-0.6 8.1 1.2Z;
   M8.1 1.2V721.6c0 0 73.2 20.7 105 16.1 39.9-5.6 63.5-61.7 105-66.9 35-4.4 74.9 1 105-13.8 41.9-20.7 60.2-90.1 92.3-108.4 30.9-17.7 74.9-13.9 101.5-33.5 63.3-46.3 5.3-81.5 76.1-145.3 0 0 47.9-24.3 61.1-46.1 19.6-32.3 18.5-61.6 18.5-111.9 0-21.7 15.2-38.8 32.3-56.5C730.2 121.6 752.7 68.8 719.8 2.9 516.8-0.6 218-0.6 8.1 1.2Z"
   repeatCount="indefinite"
   />
  
</path>

</svg>
</div>
```

- Анимация границы плюс анимация размера всего блока

```css
.container {
width:75%;
height:75%;

}

path {
fill:#2F3136;
stroke:black;
stroke-width:0;
fill-opacity:0.5;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"  viewBox="0 0 770 770" preserveAspectRatio="none" >
<defs>
<filter id='shadow'>
    <feGaussianBlur in='SourceAlpha' stdDeviation='2' />
    <feOffset dx='3' dy='3' result='blur' />
    <feMerge>
      <feMergeNode in='blur' />
      <feMergeNode in='SourceGraphic' />
    </feMerge>
  </filter>
  </defs>
<image  xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABxSm.jpg" x="10" width="1125px" height="750px" >
 
</image>
<path filter="url(#shadow)"  d="M8.1 1.2V721.6c0 0 73.2 20.7 105 16.1 39.9-5.6 63.5-61.7 105-66.9 35-4.4 74.9 1 105-13.8 41.9-20.7 60.2-90.1 92.3-108.4 30.9-17.7 74.9-13.9 101.5-33.5 63.3-46.3 5.3-81.5 76.1-145.3 0 0 47.9-24.3 61.1-46.1 19.6-32.3 18.5-61.6 18.5-111.9 0-21.7 15.2-38.8 32.3-56.5C730.2 121.6 752.7 68.8 719.8 2.9 516.8-0.6 218-0.6 8.1 1.2Z" >
<animate id="an_d" attributeName="d"
  dur="8s"
  begin="0s;an_t.end"
  values="
         M8.1 1.2V721.6c0 0 73.2 20.7 105 16.1 39.9-5.6 63.5-61.7 105-66.9 35-4.4 74.9 1 105-13.8 41.9-20.7 60.2-90.1 92.3-108.4 30.9-17.7 74.9-13.9 101.5-33.5 63.3-46.3 5.3-81.5 76.1-145.3 0 0 47.9-24.3 61.1-46.1 19.6-32.3 18.5-61.6 18.5-111.9 0-21.7 15.2-38.8 32.3-56.5C730.2 121.6 752.7 68.8 719.8 2.9 516.8-0.6 218-0.6 8.1 1.2Z;
   M8.1 1.2V721.6c0 0 76.8 2.3 110.7-24.2 67.7-52.9 94.4-1.3 137.3-18.5 40.1-16.1 39.1-57.3 105-76.1 93.8-26.8 81.5-74.9 124.6-109.6 22.3-17.9 50.6-23.4 69.2-50.8 41.5-61.1 14.5-80.4 66.9-115.4 0 0 28.1-21.9 36.9-36.9 16.5-28.3 27.7-30.3 26.5-94.6-0.4-21.7 2.5-76.9 19.6-94.6C730.2 67.3 752.7 68.8 719.8 2.9 516.8-0.6 218-0.6 8.1 1.2Z;
   M8.1 1.2V721.6c0 0 73.2 20.7 105 16.1 39.9-5.6 63.5-61.7 105-66.9 35-4.4 74.9 1 105-13.8 41.9-20.7 60.2-90.1 92.3-108.4 30.9-17.7 74.9-13.9 101.5-33.5 63.3-46.3 5.3-81.5 76.1-145.3 0 0 47.9-24.3 61.1-46.1 19.6-32.3 18.5-61.6 18.5-111.9 0-21.7 15.2-38.8 32.3-56.5C730.2 121.6 752.7 68.8 719.8 2.9 516.8-0.6 218-0.6 8.1 1.2Z"
   repeatcount="1"
   />
  <animateTransform id="an_t" attributeName="transform" type="scale" dur="12s" begin="an_d.end" values="1;0.5;0.5;1" /> 
</path>

</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: чет не работает(

Comment: @ThisMan у меня работает в FF, Chrome. в  IE, Edge не будет работать, так как им слабо поддерживать SMIL.

Comment: у меня хром, но "не стандартный" поэтому возможно поэтому

Comment: @ThisMan так попробуйте в любом другом стандартном браузере, Я только что проверил в Opera, Yandex - полёт нормальный, - всё работает

Comment: Chrom стандарт работает: Version 76.0.3809.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста векторный редактор который вы используете, спасибо

Comment: @MoloF, InkScape

Comment: @Arthur Привет Артур, давно тебя не видел, с ностальгией вспоминаю прошлый год, когда у нас всё было очень весело, была теплая компания..

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, привет! Скоро отпишусь

Comment: @ThisMan а какой именно Chrome не поддерживает Хромиум ?

Comment: а что за редактор на скринах?

Comment: @Дмытрык Inkscape

Comment: благодарю) ....