# Как оптимизировать или исправить анимацию волны?

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, css-animation, html5-canvas

Делаю примитивную анимацию волны. Но столкнулся с проблемой. Первая кривая Безье не согласуется с последующими, из-за этого пришлось спрятать этот участок за холстом.

**Как можно упростить анимацию, ведь сейчас каждый раз создается новый путь?**

Подозреваю, что можно отрисовать одиночный элемент, полуволну, которую повторить с помощью pattern, например. Но высота, ширина волны, а в дальнейшем и наклон могут меняться. Поэтому не хочу делать этот tile "в камне". Как можно сделать этот повторяющийся элемент стыкуемым и одновременно программно изменяемым? Можно ли решить с помощью SVG и CSS-анимаций?

**Пример со спрятанными волнами в начале:**

```js
const SPEED = 0.05;
const WAVE_WIDTH = 100;
const WAVE_HEIGHT = 50;
const CANVAS_WIDTH = 600;
const CANVAS_HEIGHT = 200;

let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let w = canvas.width = CANVAS_WIDTH;
let h = canvas.height = CANVAS_HEIGHT;

ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';

let wave_fase = 0;

draw();

function draw(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
    
    let waves_path_string = `M ${WAVE_WIDTH*(wave_fase - 3)} ${h}
                            V ${h/2 - WAVE_HEIGHT/2}
                            q ${WAVE_WIDTH/2} ${-WAVE_HEIGHT/2} ${WAVE_WIDTH} ${WAVE_HEIGHT/2} `;
    
    waves_path_string += 't' + ` ${WAVE_WIDTH} 0`.repeat(w/WAVE_WIDTH + 3) + ` V ${h} z`;
    
    ctx.fill(new Path2D(waves_path_string));
    
    wave_fase = (wave_fase + SPEED)%2;
    
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

**А здесь видно первую волну, которая не хочет встраиваться в общий ряд.**

```js
const SPEED = 0.01;
const WAVE_WIDTH = 60;
const WAVE_HEIGHT = 40;
const CANVAS_WIDTH = 600;
const CANVAS_HEIGHT = 200;

let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let w = canvas.width = CANVAS_WIDTH;
let h = canvas.height = CANVAS_HEIGHT;

ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';

let wave_fase = 0;

draw();

function draw(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
    
    let waves_path_string = `M ${WAVE_WIDTH*wave_fase} ${h}
                              V ${h/2 - WAVE_HEIGHT/2}
                              q ${WAVE_WIDTH/2} ${-WAVE_HEIGHT/2} ${WAVE_WIDTH} ${WAVE_HEIGHT/2} `;
    
    waves_path_string += 't' + ` ${WAVE_WIDTH} 0`.repeat(w/WAVE_WIDTH) + ` V ${h} z`;
    
    ctx.fill(new Path2D(waves_path_string));
    
    wave_fase = (wave_fase + SPEED)%2;
    
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

**А здесь тот же код на SVG,- с манипулированием атрибута `d` в `<path>`:**

```js
const SPEED = 0.05;
const WAVE_WIDTH = 100;
const WAVE_HEIGHT = 50;
const CANVAS_WIDTH = 600;
const CANVAS_HEIGHT = 200;

let svg = document.querySelector('svg');

svg.setAttribute('width',CANVAS_WIDTH);
svg.setAttribute('height',CANVAS_WIDTH);

let wave_fase = 0;

draw();

function draw(){
    
    let waves_path_string = `M ${WAVE_WIDTH*(wave_fase - 3)} ${CANVAS_HEIGHT}
                            V ${CANVAS_HEIGHT/2 - WAVE_HEIGHT/2}
                            q ${WAVE_WIDTH/2} ${-WAVE_HEIGHT/2} ${WAVE_WIDTH} ${WAVE_HEIGHT/2} `;
    
    waves_path_string += 't' + ` ${WAVE_WIDTH} 0`.repeat(CANVAS_WIDTH/WAVE_WIDTH + 3) + ` V ${CANVAS_HEIGHT} z`;
    
    svg.querySelector('path').setAttribute('d', waves_path_string);
    
    wave_fase = (wave_fase + SPEED)%2;
    
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

```html
<svg>
    <path d="" fill="blue"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: я так и не понял - в тегах svg а в примере canvas - какой вы ответ ждёте ?

Comment: @MaximLensky добавил тот же код, но с SVG. Разницы то нет. Синтаксис и описание, и, подозреваю, работа внутри браузера, `path` ничем не отличается. Возможно, тот же путь можно использовать и с `clip-path` в CSS. Вопрос в самом пути и кривых Безье. Последующие кривые завязаны на первую, потому отстраиваются по-другому, но как мне отрисовать первую волну и сделать из нее повторяющийся, стыкуемый элемент. А затем уже анимировать "паровозиком" это tile? Думаю, что "под капотом" работает одна технология, а потому любой помощи для разбора проблемы буду рад. Спасибо.

Comment: Лёня ты грузанул меня ... надо сделать такую же волну на svg ?

Comment: Если узко, то вопрос в работе кривых Безье. Как можно нарисовать первый и единственный элемент волны, который хорошо будет стыковаться. Во втором снипете видно в чем проблема. Более общий вопрос: как еще можно сделать такую волну, при том, что ее параметры должны меняться программно. Еще более обще вопрос состоит в прощупывании специфик разных подходов и технологий)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне подход автора вопроса нравится. Почему первая кривая не стыкуется с последующими?
Потому что `q` задает относительные координаты, а первая точка - на вершине волны. Последующие "полупериоды" достраиваются относительно средней линии. Т.е. получается, что начальная и управляющая точка первого гребня задраны вверх.

Кривые Безье хорошо стыкуются, когда смежные управляющие точки являются отражениями друг друга, что в решении у @Leonid достигается командой `t`, и в этом прелесть подхода.

Небольшая корректировка исправляет проблему с первым гребнем:

```js
const SPEED = 0.01;
const WAVE_WIDTH = 60;
const WAVE_HEIGHT = 80;
const CANVAS_WIDTH = 600;
const CANVAS_HEIGHT = 200;

let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let w = canvas.width = CANVAS_WIDTH;
let h = canvas.height = CANVAS_HEIGHT;

ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';

let wave_fase = 1;

draw();

function draw(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
    
    let waves_path_string = `M ${WAVE_WIDTH*wave_fase} ${h}
                             V ${h/2}
                             q ${WAVE_WIDTH/2} ${WAVE_HEIGHT} ${WAVE_WIDTH} 0 `;


    waves_path_string += 't' + ` ${WAVE_WIDTH} 0`.repeat(w/WAVE_WIDTH) + ` V ${h} z`;
    
    ctx.fill(new Path2D(waves_path_string));
    
    wave_fase = (wave_fase + SPEED) % 2;
    
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Чтобы не создавать Path каждый раз в функции draw(), можно построить путь один раз и использовать "циклический" `translate()`, но я не пробовал.

Comment: Спасибо, вот именно этого мне и не хватало! А саму анимацию да, я бы отдельный элемент на невидимом холсте сделал или pattern repeatX. Здесь уже не проблема.

Answer (score 5):

Попробуйте такой способ, он больше на волну похож.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

const draw = (delta) => {
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.4)";

  const randomLeft = Math.abs(Math.pow(Math.sin(delta / 1000), 2)) * 100;
  const randomRight = Math.abs(Math.pow(Math.sin((delta / 1000) + 10), 2)) * 100;
  const randomLeftConstraint = Math.abs(Math.pow(Math.sin((delta / 1000) + 2), 2)) * 100;
  const randomRightConstraint = Math.abs(Math.pow(Math.sin((delta / 1000) + 1), 2)) * 100;

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, randomLeft);

  ctx.bezierCurveTo(canvas.width / 3, randomLeftConstraint, canvas.width / 3 * 2, randomRightConstraint, canvas.width, randomRight);
  ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.lineTo(0, canvas.height);
  ctx.lineTo(0, randomLeft);

  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
}
requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 5):

> Подозреваю, что можно отрисовать одиночный элемент, полуволну, которую
> повторить с помощью pattern, например.

---

> Первая кривая Безье не согласуется с последующими, из-за этого
> пришлось спрятать этот участок за холстом.

1. Создаем одну волну с помощью кривых Безье

```html
<svg class="editorial"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   viewBox="0 24 150 28"
   preserveAspectRatio="none">
<path 
    id="gentle-wave" fill="#4579e2"
     d="m -160,44.4 c 30,0 58,
        -18 87.7,-18 30.3,0 58.3,
        18 87.3,18 30,0 58,-18 88,
        -18 30,0 58,18 88,18 l 0,
        34.5 -351,0 z" /> 
</svg>
```

2. Клонируем эту волну три раза с разным цветом закраски

```html
<svg class="editorial"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   viewBox="0 24 150 28"
   preserveAspectRatio="none">
 <defs>
  <path 
    id="gentle-wave"
     d="m -160,44.4 c 30,0 58,
        -18 87.7,-18 30.3,0 58.3,
        18 87.3,18 30,0 58,-18 88,
        -18 30,0 58,18 88,18 l 0,
        34.5 -351,0 z" />
 </defs>
  <g class="parallax">
   <use xlink:href="#gentle-wave" x="50" y="0" fill="#4579e2"/>
   <use xlink:href="#gentle-wave" x="50" y="3" fill="#3461c1"/>
   <use xlink:href="#gentle-wave" x="50" y="6" fill="#2d55aa"/>  
  </g>
</svg>
```

3. Добавляем анимацию волн CSS

```
@keyframes move-forever {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-90px, 0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(85px, 0%);
  }
}
```

Ниже полный код:

```css
.parallax > use {
  animation: move-forever 12s linear infinite;
}
.parallax > use:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: -2s;
}
.parallax > use:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -2s;
  animation-duration: 5s;
}
.parallax > use:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: -4s;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}

@keyframes move-forever {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-90px, 0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(85px, 0%);
  }
}
.editorial {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 17em;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #323232;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 9em 0 0 0;
}

.content {
  font-family: 'Lato',sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #2d55aa;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 75vh;
  margin: -.1em 0 0 0;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #eee;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<svg class="editorial"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   viewBox="0 24 150 28"
   preserveAspectRatio="none">
 <defs>
  <path 
    id="gentle-wave"
     d="m -160,44.4 c 30,0 58,
        -18 87.7,-18 30.3,0 58.3,
        18 87.3,18 30,0 58,-18 88,
        -18 30,0 58,18 88,18 l 0,
        34.5 -351,0 z" />
 </defs>
  <g class="parallax">
   <use xlink:href="#gentle-wave" x="50" y="0" fill="#4579e2"/>
   <use xlink:href="#gentle-wave" x="50" y="3" fill="#3461c1"/>
   <use xlink:href="#gentle-wave" x="50" y="6" fill="#2d55aa"/>  
  </g>
</svg>
```

За основу взят и переработан топик @Andy Fitzsimon  на [codepen](https://codepen.io/andyfitz/pen/akAKdV)

### Update

По результатам обсуждения в комментариях, я понял, что автору вопроса нужно какое-то универсальное решение, где ничего не надо считать и получать результат, изменяя только входные данные.
Вот великолепный [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1029466/28748) **@Stranger in the Q**

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  wave(20 + i * 3, 70 - i * 10, 2 + 1 * Math.random(), 0.4 + i * 0.05, 40 + i * 25)

function wave(amp, freq, time, scaleY, translateY) {
  let pts = [];
  for (var x = 0; x < 2000; x += 10)
    pts.push([x, (Math.sin(x / freq) * amp + translateY).toFixed(1)])
  svg.innerHTML += `<path class="wave" d="M${pts.join('L')}v1000h-2000"
        style="--t:${time}s;--sy:${scaleY};--tx:-${freq*2*Math.PI}px" />`;
}
```

```css
.wave {
  fill: steelblue;
  stroke: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  animation: wave var(--t) linear infinite;
}

@keyframes wave {
    0% {transform: scale(1, var(--sy)) translate(0px, 0px)}
   50% {transform:                     translate(calc(var(--tx)*0.5), 0px)}
  100% {transform: scale(1, var(--sy)) translate(var(--tx), 0px)}
}
```

```html
<svg id=svg viewBox="0 0 1000 175" preserveAspectRatio="none"></svg>
```

Надеюсь это поможет в решении задачи.

Comment: Пока не понял, за счет кубической Безье получается стыкуемый элемент сделать? Но `translate` -90 --> 85? Не скрывается здесь сам момент нестыковки? По одиночному элементу не скажешь, концы можно свести. За уникальный подход отдельное спасибо, буду изучать.

Comment: @Leonid Да, именно так, стыкуется несколько кривых Безье в одной волне, потом они целиком клонируются `<use>` и каждый экземпляр волны смещается вправо с позиции -90px до 85px с задержкой смещения относительно друг друга `animation-delay`

Comment: Да, просто странно, что при ширине элемента в 150 перемещение идет с разницей в 175)))) Это подгонка какая-то, или стилями где-то переопределена ширина базового элемента. А так получается, что идет подгонка до совпадающего участка.

Comment: @Leonid ты в плену собственного подхода. Смещение волны никак не связано со стыковкой нескольких кривых Безье в одной волне.  Разница в значениях размера svg и величине суммарного смещения волны в абсолютном значении может быть любой.  Просто волна при отрицательном значении смещения не видна (находится вне видимости документа svg)  И при многократном повторении создается эффект бесконечности движения

Comment: Я не про стыковку кривых, а просто про начало и конец отдельного элемента.  Разница по пути (от -160 до -351 --> 191), сам `viewbox` шириной 150, в `<use>` берется отступ +50, а в анимации диапазон 175)))) Это похоже на долгую и кропотливую подгонку под нужный результат, но никак не  на прогнозируемый. https://jsfiddle.net/rfbyxj3p/ - вот изображение не обрезанного рисунка, он на самом деле двойной, значит он также удаляет начальную часть.

Comment: @Leonid согласен, что какие-то расчеты всегда должны быть. Иначе то как, лепить от балды любые цифры и ожидать верного результата, такого не бывает.  В частности здесь длина волны составляет именно 351px проверяется getBBox()

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sedrwbhf/ - не правильно я прочитал, -351 возврат по относительным координатам для замыкания. То есть 351 и есть ширина общего элемента, он берет от 0, отрезая 160 слева. Читаемости это не добавляет просто, да и зачем то это делалось, но результат как-то сошелся. Только боюсь, что если тронуть хоть один параметр - все рассыплется.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127754/discussion-between-leonid-and-alexandr-tt).

Answer (score 1):

Наверстал вам «бурю в стакане» на CSS:

```css
body {
    background: #172b3c;
    margin: 0;
}
.sea {
    width: 100vh;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: auto;
}
.wave {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    left: -40%;
    top: 56%;
    background-color: #57d0ff;
    border-radius: 40%;
    animation: wave 7s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes wave {
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="sea">
    <div class="wave"></div>
</div>
```