# Проблемы с анимацией на canvas не получается слизать

Tags: javascript, canvas

https://happyegg.com/ - есть вот такой сайт. В банере анимация( первая секция)

Совсем не понимаю как можно слизать ее с этого сайта, может кто-то пример может предоставить или подскажет куда копать , сижу сутки и ничего не получается

так же ниже есть секция при наведение на картинку они используют санвас, но аналогично как и выше, ничего не выходит

Спасибо заранее!

Comment: Какая составляющая вас интересует? Там довольно комплексная анимация, нужен принцип, по которому выбирается где пройдет линия, тут она зависит от положения курсора+ какое-то разбиение пространства есть, т.к. поведение в разных частях сайта разное

Comment: Меня интересует вот эта анимация - https://prnt.sc/siwvs4 

То есть плавные движение блока при движение мыши (хотелось бы понять как это вообще обзывается, называется) что бы знать куда копать и т.д.

и еще вот эта анимация https://prnt.sc/siwxa8

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1018740/188366

Comment: нарисовать на svg или canvas картинку

Comment: ага, благодарю! Но это например самостоятельно движение идет , первая часть можно сказать) А вот , когда движение курсора идет , куда копать, что бы движение этой свг было?

Comment: ну я написал, нужно придумать принцип, а потом его реализовать, например точки тянутся к курсору по какому-то принципу, а потом они соединяются кривой безье

Comment: зачем придумывать? не совсем понимаю Вас.

Собственно принцип работы как на сайте, который кидал ссылку

Comment: так а как увидеть принцип глядя на эффект? иногда это сразу видно, но тут я не вижу закономерности, нужно изучать код..., то есть кое что прослеживается, а кое что нет, я не понял сходу что обеспечивает скачки, тут есть какое-то разбиение на зоны, в которых правила отличаются

Comment: похоже что имеет место быть диаграмма вороного

Comment: ладно, буду смотреть код тогда, хорошо. Но может у Вас есть еще маломальские примеры похожие на такую анимацию при движение курсора?

Comment: я не уверен, но кажется это тут https://i.imgur.com/AF4nne2.png

Comment: это пол беды) Еще бы понять что к чему там. Вот например вот эти import'ы куда могут вести - https://prnt.sc/sixo1o ? или они не особо влияют на эту анимацию ? 

(Впервые вижу vue + canvas никогда не тыкал, извиняюсь за такие глупые вопросы)

Comment: это можно найти в папке webpack в одноименных директориях

Comment: по последнему скрину становится понятно, что точки, которые нужно соединять, двигаются по горизонтали, а по вертикали они привязаны относительно экрана

Comment: к сожалению двигается оно по горизонтали или по вертикали мне ничего не даст.

Ладно , спасибо и на этом

Comment: Вы меня не поняли, не оно, опорные точки, по которым оно строится, я сделаю пример когда освобожусь

Comment: хорошо, спасибо! буду ждать

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В оригинале конечно же какая-то более сложная закономерность, но это роли не играет все будет как-то так же, считаем на сколько нужно сдвинуть каждую точку в каждом кадре, в зависимости от того, где сейчас курсор:

```js
let count = 300;
let mouse = [innerWidth/2, innerHeight/2];
let pts = [...Array(count)].map((_, i) => [innerWidth/2, i/(count-1)*innerHeight]);
let svg = document.querySelector('svg')
let path = document.querySelector('svg path')
addEventListener('resize', resize);
addEventListener('mousemove', move);
resize();
requestAnimationFrame(upd);

function upd() {
  let d = ['M', 0, 0];
  pts.forEach(p => {
    let dx = mouse[0] - p[0];
    let dy = mouse[1] - p[1];
    p[0] += dx/30*(Math.cos(dy/innerHeight*6)*0.4+0.6);
    d.push('L', ...p);
  });
  d.push('L', 0, innerHeight, 'Z');
  path.setAttribute('d', d.join(' '))
  requestAnimationFrame(upd);
}

function move(e) {
  mouse[0] = e.x;
  mouse[1] = e.y;
}

function resize(){
  svg.setAttribute('width', innerWidth)
  svg.setAttribute('height', innerHeight)
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <path></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: боже мой, благодарю вас!!!

Comment: Не знаю, сильно нагло наверное будет. Но я уже от безысходности. Может Вы знаете как и вот эту анимацию сделать ? https://prnt.sc/sj806j при наведение на картинку ее как волнами штырит https://happyegg.com/

или опять же, если прошуршать Ваш код можно как-то надумать и эту анимацию?

Comment: ну в целом это очень похожий алгоритм, точки двигаем в зависимости от положения курсора... могу завтра попробовать сделать...